# Django CMS: BadMigrationError while migrating djangocms_table in version 3.5.2

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-cms

I want to install djangocms_table plugin.My current Django cms version is 3.5.2

I followed the below steps to do the same.

> 1.pip install djangocms_table
>
> 2.Added 'djangocms_table' to  INSTALLED_APPS
>
> 3.manage.py migrate djangocms_table

After I ran migrate command got the below exception.

```
System check identified some issues:
 
WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/host/lendingstream/src/web/ConsumerUI/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 25, in handle
    call_command("migrate", **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 182, in build_graph
    self.load_disk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 123, in load_disk
    "creating Django migrations." % app_config.label
django.db.migrations.loader.BadMigrationError: Migrated app 'djangocms_table' contains South migrations. Make sure all numbered South migrations are deleted prior to creating Django migrations.
```

Comment: djangocms_table hasn't been updated since Django 1.7, I wouldn't use it if I were you. The error says it's still using `South` for the migrations, so that's not compatible.

Comment: @dirkgroten - Thanks! Is there any other plugin in Django cms that support table related operations.

Comment: No idea, you might want to search on [Django packages](https://djangopackages.org)